# Assignment operator could not be generated even when I overload the = operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, warnings

My class is polymorphic and should not be used to be ='d anyways. It has a member which is of type Font& and as a result the compiler cannot generate an = operator. So I just created dummy implementations of the assignment and copy constructor, put them in the private of the class, but it still warns me about assignment operator not able to get generated. How else can I get rid of this warning?

Thanks

Warning 9   warning C4512: 'AguiWidget' : assignment operator could not be generated    c:\users\josh\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\agui\alleg_5\agui\aguiwidget.hpp    250

Comment: Post some code please. (bis repetitas)

Comment: Okay, that's a lot of code, can you tell us what line it's actually complaining about?

Comment: You shouldn't have removed the entire code, just post the relevant sections. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The assignment operator that the compiler is warning you about is the one for your own class. What you have now is:

```
AguiWidget& operator=(const AguiFont &tmp);
```

What you need is:

```
AguiWidget& operator=(const AguiWidget &tmp);
```

Comment: You should also declare it private -- which makes any attempted use of the copy assignment operator a compile-time error (as opposed to link-time).

Comment: @Tabber33: It already was private. The OP removed his code just a moment back.

Comment: @Tabber33: Oops, sorry. The OP mentioned "put them in the private of the class" in his question, so I believed so. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it.  This won't work, of course, if you're actually trying to use those operators.

Are you sure you got the signatures right?  Did you make them for each class, base and deriveds?

Comment: you have to make it for each type?

Comment: Yeah.  That's actually a really stupid and useless warning; unless you actually attempt to USE those operators it doesn't matter and it blocks a lot of useful constructs (boost causes it to vomit a billion of them).  You should consider globally disabling it.

Answer (score 2):

Use [boost::noncopyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/utility.htm?sess=3ae51a868987891964632d9e613df214#Class_noncopyable).

```
class AGUI_CORE_DECLSPEC AguiWidget : private boost::noncopyable
```

NOTE:

boost::noncopyable will be enforced for all sub-classes as well.

EDIT:

Wow... that's one scary class...

Use the [pimpl idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/024.htm) to reduce code interdependencies and improve interface readability.

Also you should try to avoid protected member variables (as much as possible) as it breaks encapsulation.

Comment: There's no need to drag Boost into this for something so simple (unless he's already using Boost). All the OP has to do is fix his assignment operator to accept an argument of type `AguiWidget` instead of `AguiFont`. And that is a scary class :-D

Comment: True enough. However, if he doesn't use boost then he should create his own "noncopyable" class as it improves readability and clearly shows intentions.

Comment: @ Praetorian how else would you propose making a widget class with callbacks for almost 30 events, GuiChan's widget class is pretty big too.

Comment: @ronag the class is abstract anyways

Comment: @ronag how will derived classes of AguiWidget override without it being protected?

Comment: @milo. Ok. Could you  What does it being abstract have to do with anything?

Comment: Well by being abstract, an AguiWidget is uncopyable

Comment: @Milo: It is hard to answer that without seeing (and understanding) all your code. One possibility is to group callbacks into types and delegate responsibility of handling that callback type to another class. The `AguiWidget` class can then inherit from these handler classes.

Comment: @milo. Even if it's abstract, sub-classes can still be copyable... which is probably not what you want.

Comment: doing something like AguiLabel lab = AguiLabel("blah"); works just fine though, ... if ever anyone tries to call the copy constructor or the assignment operator, it will fail which is fine by me.